# 4 columns with values into 2 columns using colnames

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have the following 4 columns in my data frame in R:

```
A   T    C    G
Ref NA Var NA
NA Ref Var NA
Var NA Ref NA
```

And would like to turn it into:

```
Ref Var

A C

T C

C A
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape into 'long' format and then switch it to wide format with the `names_from` the 'value' column after creating a sequence column grouped by 'value'.  The `na` (missing value) seems to be string instead of the `NA`, so changed it first to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1[df1 == "na"] <- NA

pivot_longer(df1, everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(value) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  ref   var  
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A     C    
#2 T     C    
#3 C     A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("ref", NA, "var"), T = c(NA, "ref", NA), 
    C = c("var", "var", "ref"), G = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is a one-liner in base R

```
as.data.frame(sapply(c("ref", "var"), function(col) apply(DF, 1, function(x) names(x)[x == col])))
```

> ```
>   ref var
> 1   A   C
> 2   T   C
> 3   C   A
> ```

There is no special treatment of `"na"` values required.

In many cases, reshaping is my preferred approach because column names are treated as data. Here is an abbreviated version which requires only to reshape from wide to long format:

```
long <- reshape2::melt(t(DF))
as.data.frame(sapply(c("ref", "var"), function(x) long$Var1[long$value == x]))
```

> ```
>   ref var
> 1   A   C
> 2   T   C
> 3   C   A
> ```

Note that `DF` is transposed before reshaping to ensure row-wise operation as requested by the OP.

NB: All solution assume implicitely that `"ref"` and `"var"`, resp., appear only once in each row.

Comment: Thanks! apply functions seem to be very useful for data processing!